# Chromebook running ubuntu - hardware required for unity

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to buy a chromebook and install either Ubuntu 14 or Ubuntu 16 on it. I looked at the unity specs, and did some research, but it doesn't appear certain unity will run.

I'm wondering, what specs for a chromebook will I need to run the unity GUI interface on it to do some light development work?

Further, Is dual-core processor enough to run unity or do I need quad-core cpu? Do I need 4gb of ram, or more?

Also, if you can recommend one that will work for this need?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need at least, and probably more than, 4GB of RAM in order to use Unity effectively in a Linux environment.

Dual core should be enough for things to run, however, everything is going to be more responsive if you're using a quad core system.

You will need to get the best graphics hardware you can find, Intel HD may work but I would be more optimistic about a Tegra GPU being capable of running Unity.  Graphics drivers will probably be a hurdle here.

A Chromebook is going to run out of disk space very quickly.  Unity itself takes around 2.5 GB after it is installed, and each game project, depending on graphics and audio resources is going to consume disk space very quickly.  32GB hard drive would be the absolute minimum, and I can still foresee the inevitably full hard drive causing issues.

Ultimately I would suggest finding a laptop with higher specs than a typical Chromebook if you're serious about using Unity on it.

My best advice here, though, is don't buy a Chromebook for this purpose unless you're confident in the retailer being open-minded about returns.